# Where should I write my model code in cakephp 3?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I am learning cakephp 3 but I am having a hard time understanding where I should write my code. I understand the model has been split between Tables and Entities, but how do I know where my code should go?

For example, I want to have a field in my database to be updated every time a user edits his profile. I want to add my code in the model, because it is my understanding the model should be "fat" and the controllers "thin". I can add it on my controller but I feel I am violating that MVC rule.

So where should I implement this? More importantly, how can I code that correctly in the model?

Thanks

Comment: Try to bake your model, controller and view and see the generated code. You can learn from them. http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/bake/usage.html

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Bookmarker](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/bookmarks/intro.html#creating-the-finder-method) tutorial you want to do the following:

> In **src/Model/Table/BookmarksTable.php** add the following:

```
// The $query argument is a query builder instance.
// The $options array will contain the 'tags' option we passed
// to find('tagged') in our controller action.
public function findTagged(Query $query, array $options)
{
    return $this->find()
        ->distinct(['Bookmarks.id'])
        ->matching('Tags', function ($q) use ($options) {
            return $q->where(['Tags.title IN' => $options['tags']]);
        });
}
```

So you'll want to add any "model" code into your table files.